# Jquery 1.9.1 Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery

I've been updating to Jquery 1.9.1 have run into a problem. In the Jquery code itself I get the following;

```
//Serialize an array of form elements or a set of
//key/values into a query string
jQuery.param = function( a, traditional ) {
var prefix,
s = [],
add = function( key, value ) {
// If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );

**Uncaught TypeError: Object function Document() { [native code] } has no method 'apply'**
};
```

I can't seem to backtrack it to specific code.  I did change a .live('click' to .on('click';

```
$(document).on("click", "#candidatesubmit", function() {
    var strForm = $("form").serialize();
    //alert(strForm);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'actEditStatusForm.cfm',
        data: strForm,
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // show error 
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(response1, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            ColdFusion.Grid.refresh('candidatesGrid', true);
```

The post gets done so that part seems to be working fine. But the following code does not work;

```
<cfsavecontent variable="canddivscript">
<script>
function initDateStuff2Script() {
$(function() {
    //alert('xxxxx');
    $('input.datestuff2').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
});
}
</script>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfoutput>
<cfhtmlhead text="#canddivscript##chr(13)##chr(10)#">
</cfoutput>
<cfset ajaxOnLoad("initDateStuff2Script")>
```

Only one particular input field with class="datestuff2" does anything and that's to put up a mask yyyy/mm/dd when I type a date.  The other input fields do nothing. I suppose I could go back to Jquery 1.7

The code is quite lengthy so I can't post it all here.

Comment: check out this: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ to see what has changed in 1.9

Comment: Yes, I reviewed that document and found the things that pertained to me.  But I haven't had time to review the migrate plugin yet.  I guess I really should give it a whirl.

Comment: Well, that didn't work out very well.  I got a message that the page was block for insecure content (repeated 2 times) and no other direction.  I still get the "uncaught typeerror".